# JSONexception while fetching JSONArray JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, server-response

Getting JSON Exception while fetching json response from server.I have tried many solutions given on stackoverflow but thats not working.Below is my code for sending parameters to the sever and fetching json.Please help me guys.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

JSON Response from server:

Note:"upload" is an JSONarray .

```
  {
        "code": 200,
        "upload": {
        "Booking": {
        "id": "17",
        "contributor_id": "16",
        "table_of_content_id": "1",
        "composition_id": "12",
        "completion": "2017-05-20",
        "approved": null,
        "cdn_id": null,
        "secret_token": null,
        "uploaded_on": null,
        "created": "2017-05-09 14:41:49",
        "modified": "2017-05-09 14:41:49"
        },
        "TableOfContent": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "গোরা",
        "category_id": "1",
        "language_id": "1",
        "created": "2016-03-09 03:39:01",
        "modified": "2016-03-09 14:39:01"
        }
        }
        }
```

This is how i am trying to do it.

```
public void forwardtoOurServer() {
        JSONObject jsonObject=null;
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";
        StringRequest postStringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, RECORD_COMPOSITION_API,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Audio Upload Response Check :" + response);


                        try {
                            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                            String code = json.getString("code");
                            JSONArray obj = json.getJSONArray("upload");
                            Log.d(TAG, "obj Response Check :" + obj);
                            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.d(TAG, "jsonObject Response Check :" + jsonObject);
                                JSONObject bookings = obj.getJSONObject(Integer.parseInt("Booking"));

//                                int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
//
//                                String type = jsonObject.getString("type");

                                // retrieve the values like this so on..

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error Response Check :" + error);

                    }
                }) {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("data[Booking][id]",bookingId);
                params.put("data[Booking][contributor_id]",contributor_id);
                params.put("data[Booking][table_of_content_id]",tocId);
                params.put("data[Booking][cdn_id]",vs_cdn_id);
                params.put("data[Booking][secret_token]",secret_token);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
                sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                Date now = new Date();
                String strDate = sdf.format(now);
                params.put("data[Booking][uploaded_on]",strDate);
                Log.d(TAG, "Params :" + params);
                return params;

            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                headers.put("UUID", device_uuid);
                headers.put("APPID", "2A192A0C22");
                headers.put("USERID", "1");
                headers.put("PLATFORM", "Andriod");
                headers.put("APP_REQUEST", "1");
                headers.put("PLATFORMVERSION",androidOS);
                return headers;
            }

        };


        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postStringRequest, tag_string_req);

    }
```

Log:

```
06-07 12:44:18.865 13701-13903/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject D/Null: Params :{data[Booking][cdn_id]=326929293, data[Booking][table_of_content_id]=1, data[Booking][id]=16, data[Booking][secret_token]=s-0DT7x, data[Booking][contributor_id]=16, data[Booking][uploaded_on]=2017-06-07T07:14:18Z}
06-07 12:44:20.629 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject D/Null: Audio Upload Response Check :{"code":200,"upload":{"Booking":{"id":"17","contributor_id":"16","table_of_content_id":"1","composition_id":"12","completion":"2017-05-20","approved":null,"cdn_id":null,"secret_token":null,"uploaded_on":null,"created":"2017-05-09 14:41:49","modified":"2017-05-09 14:41:49"},"TableOfContent":{"id":"1","name":"\u0997\u09cb\u09b0\u09be","category_id":"1","language_id":"1","created":"2016-03-09 03:39:01","modified":"2016-03-09 14:39:01"},"Composition":{"id":"12","content":"\u09ac\u09bf\u09a8\u09df \u0993 \u0997\u09cb\u09b0\u09be \u09aa\u09b0\u09c7\u09b6\u09c7\u09b0 \u09ac\u09be\u09dc\u09bf \u09b9\u0987\u09a4\u09c7 \u09b0\u09be\u09b8\u09cd\u09a4\u09be\u09df \u09ac\u09be\u09b9\u09bf\u09b0 \u09b9\u0987\u09b2\u09c7 \u09ac\u09bf\u09a8\u09df \u0995\u09b9\u09bf\u09b2, &quot;\u0997\u09cb\u09b0\u09be, \u098f\u0995\u099f\u09c1 \u0986\u09b8\u09cd\u09a4\u09c7 \u0986\u09b8\u09cd\u09a4\u09c7 \u099a\u09b2\u09cb \u09ad\u09be\u0987-- \u09a4\u09cb\u09ae\u09be\u09b0 \u09aa\u09be \u09a6\u09c1\u099f\u09cb \u0986\u09ae\u09be\u09a6\u09c7\u09b0 \u099a\u09c7\u09df\u09c7 \u0985\u09a8\u09c7\u0995 \u09ac\u09dc\u09cb-- \u0993\u09b0 \u099a\u09be\u09b2\u099f\u09be \u098f\u0995\u099f\u09c1 \u0996\u09be\u099f\u09cb \u09a8\u09be \u0995\u09b0\u09b2\u09c7 \u09a4\u09cb\u09ae\u09be\u09b0 \u09b8\u0999\u09cd\u0997\u09c7 \u09af\u09c7\u09a4\u09c7 \u0986\u09ae\u09b0\u09be \u09b9\u09be\u0981\u09aa\u09bf\u09df\u09c7 \u09aa\u09dc\u09bf\u0964&quot;\n \u0997\u09cb\u09b0\u09be \u0995\u09b9\u09bf\u09b2, &quot;\u0986\u09ae\u09bf \u098f\u0995\u09b2\u09be\u0987 \u09af\u09c7\u09a4\u09c7 \u099a\u09be\u0987, \u0986\u09ae\u09be\u09b0 \u0986\u099c \u0985\u09a8\u09c7\u0995 \u0995\u09a5\u09be \u09ad\u09be\u09ac\u09ac\u09be\u09b0 \u0986\u099b\u09c7\u0964&quot;\n \u09ac\u09b2\u09bf\u09df\u09be \u09a4\u09be\u09b9\u09be\u09b0 \u09b8\u09cd\u09ac\u09be\u09ad\u09be\u09ac\u09bf\u0995 \u09a6\u09cd\u09b0\u09c1\u09a4\u0997\u09a4\u09bf\u09a4\u09c7 \u09b8\u09c7 \u09ac\u09c7\u0997\u09c7 \u099a\u09b2\u09bf\u09df\u09be \u0997\u09c7\u09b2\u0964\n \u09ac\u09bf\u09a8\u09df\u09c7\u09b0 \u09ae\u09a8\u09c7 \u0986\u0998\u09be\u09a4 \u09b2\u09be\u0997\u09bf\u09b2\u0964 \u09b8\u09c7 \u0986\u099c \u0997\u09cb\u09b0\u09be\u09b0 \u09ac\u09bf\u09b0\u09c1\u09a6\u09cd\u09a7\u09c7 \u09ac\u09bf\u09a6\u09cd\u09b0\u09cb\u09b9 \u0995\u09b0\u09bf\u09df\u09be \u09a4\u09be\u09b9\u09be\u09b0 \u09a8\u09bf\u09df\u09ae \u09ad\u0999\u09cd\u0997 \u0995\u09b0\u09bf\u09df\u09be\u099b\u09c7\u0964 \u09b8\u09c7 \u09b8\u09ae\u09cd\u09ac\u09a8\u09cd\u09a7\u09c7 \u0997\u09cb\u09b0\u09be\u09b0 \u0995\u09be\u099b\u09c7 \u09a4\u09bf\u09b0\u09b8\u09cd\u0995\u09be\u09b0 \u09ad\u09cb\u0997 \u0995\u09b0\u09bf\u09b2\u09c7 \u09b8\u09c7 \u0996\u09c1\u09b6\u09bf \u09b9\u0987\u09a4\u0964 \u098f\u0995\u099f\u09be \u099d\u09dc \u09b9\u0987\u09df\u09be \u0997\u09c7\u09b2\u09c7\u0987 \u09a4\u09be\u09b9\u09be\u09a6\u09c7\u09b0 \u099a\u09bf\u09b0\u09a6\u09bf\u09a8\u09c7\u09b0 \u09ac\u09a8\u09cd\u09a7\u09c1\u09a4\u09cd\u09ac\u09c7\u09b0 \u0986\u0995\u09be\u09b6 \u09b9\u0987\u09a4\u09c7 \u0997\u09c1\u09ae\u099f \u0995\u09be\u099f\u09bf\u09df\u09be \u09af\u09be\u0987\u09a4 \u098f\u09ac\u0982 \u09b8\u09c7 \u09b9\u09be\u0981\u09aa \u099b\u09be\u09dc\u09bf\u09df\u09be \u09ac\u09be\u0981\u099a\u09bf\u09a4\u0964\n \u09a4\u09be\u09b9\u09be \u099b\u09be\u09dc\u09be \u0986\u09b0-\u098f\u0995\u099f\u09be \u0995\u09a5\u09be \u09a4\u09be\u09b9\u09be\u0995\u09c7 \u09aa\u09c0\u09dc\u09be \u09a6\u09bf\u09a4\u09c7\u099b\u09bf\u09b2\u0964 \u0986\u099c \u09b9\u09a0\u09be\u09ce \u0997\u09cb\u09b0\u09be \u09aa\u09b0\u09c7\u09b6\u09c7\u09b0 \u09ac\u09be\u09dc\u09bf\u09a4\u09c7 \u09aa\u09cd\u09b0\u09a5\u09ae \u0986\u09b8\u09bf\u09df\u09be\u0987 \u09ac\u09bf\u09a8\u09df\u0995\u09c7 \u09b8\u09c7\u0996\u09be\u09a8\u09c7 \u09ac\u09a8\u09cd\u09a7\u09c1\u09ad\u09be\u09ac\u09c7 \u09ac\u09b8\u09bf\u09df\u09be \u09a5\u09be\u0995\u09bf\u09a4\u09c7 \u09a6\u09c7\u0996\u09bf\u09df\u09be \u09a8\u09bf\u09b6\u09cd\u099a\u09df\u0987 \u09ae\u09a8\u09c7 \u0995\u09b0\u09bf\u09df\u09be\u099b\u09c7 \u09ac\u09bf\u09a8\u09df \u098f \u09ac\u09be\u
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"Booking":{"id":"17","contributor_id":"16","table_of_content_id":"1","composition_id":"12","completion":"2017-05-20","approved":null,"cdn_id":null,"secret_token":null,"uploaded_on":null,"created":"2017-05-09 14:41:49","modified":"2017-05-09 14:41:49"},"TableOfContent":{"id":"1","name":"গোরা","category_id":"1","language_id":"1","created":"2016-03-09 03:39:01","modified":"2016-03-09 14:39:01"},"Composition":{"id":"12","content":"বিনয় ও গোরা পরেশের বাড়ি হইতে রাস্তায় বাহির হইলে বিনয় কহিল, &quot;গোরা, একটু আস্তে আস্তে চলো ভাই-- তোমার পা দুটো আমাদের চেয়ে অনেক বড়ো-- ওর চালটা একটু খাটো না করলে তোমার সঙ্গে যেতে আমরা হাঁপিয়ে পড়ি।&quot;\n গোরা কহিল, &quot;আমি একলাই যেতে চাই, আমার আজ অনেক কথা ভাববার আছে।&quot;\n বলিয়া তাহার স্বাভাবিক দ্রুতগতিতে সে বেগে চলিয়া গেল।\n বিনয়ের মনে আঘাত লাগিল। সে আজ গোরার বিরুদ্ধে বিদ্রোহ করিয়া তাহার নিয়ম ভঙ্গ করিয়াছে। সে সম্বন্ধে গোরার কাছে তিরস্কার ভোগ করিলে সে খুশি হইত। একটা ঝড় হইয়া গেলেই তাহাদের চিরদিনের বন্ধুত্বের আকাশ হইতে গুমট কাটিয়া যাইত এবং সে হাঁপ ছাড়িয়া বাঁচিত।\n তাহা ছাড়া আর-একটা কথা তাহাকে পীড়া দিতেছিল। আজ হঠাৎ গোরা পরেশের বাড়িতে প্রথম আসিয়াই বিনয়কে সেখানে বন্ধুভাবে বসিয়া থাকিতে দেখিয়া নিশ্চয়ই মনে করিয়াছে বিনয় এ বাড়িতে সর্বদাই যাতায়াত করে। অবশ্য, যাতায়াত করিলে যে কোনো অপরাধ আছে তাহা নয়; গোরা যাহাই বলুক পরেশবাবুর সুশিক্ষিত পরিবারের সঙ্গে অন্তরঙ্গভাবে পরিচিত হইবার সুযোগ পাওয়া বিনয় একটা বিশেষ লাভ বলিয়া গণ্য করিতেছে; ইঁহাদের সঙ্গে মেশামেশি করাতে গোরা যদি কোনো দোষ দেখে তবে সেটা তাহার নিতান্ত গোঁড়ামি; কিন্তু পূর্বের কথাবার্তায় গোরা নাকি জানিয়াছে যে বিনয় পরেশবাবুর বাড়িতে যাওয়া-আসা করে না, আজ সহসা তাহার মনে হইতে পারে যে সে কথাটা সত্য নয়। বিশেষত বরদাসুন্দরী তাহাকে বিশেষ করিয়া ঘরে ডাকিয়া লইয়া গেলেন, সেখানে তাঁহার মেয়েদের সঙ্গে তাহার আলাপ হইতে লাগিল-- গোরার তীক্ষ্ণ লক্ষ হইতে ইহা এড়াইয়া যায় নাই। মেয়েদের সঙ্গে এইরূপ মেলামেশায় ও বরদাসুন্দরীর আত্মীয়তায় মনে মনে বিনয় ভার�
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:588)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.RecordComposition$16.onResponse(RecordComposition.java:704)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.RecordComposition$16.onResponse(RecordComposition.java:694)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
06-07 12:44:20.663 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-07 12:44:20.664 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-07 12:44:20.664 13701-13701/com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: where is error log cat?

Comment: post error log cat

Comment: the message of exception will tell you what is wrong with your parsing or with your JSON.

Comment: you are parsing string to int Integer.parseInt("Booking")

Comment: you are using Invalid json format

it should be JSONARRAY:[ {JSONOBJECT}]
you are using  JSONARRAY:[ Key:{JSONOBJECT}]

Comment: First there is an JSON object inside that there is an JSON Array (upload),Inside upload there are JSON objects

Comment: @Shubham Goel could you please suggest me the correct way to do it.

Comment: ok, now the JSON is valid, but the `upload` is a JSONObject, not a JSONArray.

Comment: You can create a java pojo to map your json..see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867961/how-to-map-jsonobject-in-java-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you are using `JSONArray obj = json.getJSONArray("upload");`  but "upload" is jsonObject.

In your java code use `JSONObject bookings = obj.getJSONObject("upload").getJSONObject("Booking");`

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid, Remove the keys for items in the json array (Booking, modified) or move those objects from the array . Your json parsing code should be

```
try {
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
      String code = json.getString("code");

      JsonObject upload = jsonObject.getJSONObject("upload");
      //get the other object like this

      } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();

      }
```

Comment: @Mobo, it is invalid. As for JSON specification, JSONArray can't have keys, only values. And your JSONArray has keys. It is invalid.

Comment: now your json is valid, change the code also. you don't have a json array in your response

Comment: but when i am trying without json array ,then also its showing JSON Exception, saying json type mismatch for upload

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        String code = json.getString("code");
                        JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject("upload");
                        JSONObject objbooking = obj.getJSONObject("Booking");
                        JSONObject objtable = obj.getJSONObject("TableOfContent");

                       //you can get values like below

                       String idbooking = objbooking.getString("id");
                       String idtable = objtable.getString("id");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```